# Rails Generate Controller ArgumentError empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running `$ rails g controller posts` on the command line returns an ArgumentError. Basically that an empty string is not a supported controller name.

This error message is generated:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:260:in `block (2 levels) in check_controller_and_action': '' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

So far, I've tried disabling my bash_config file, and reinstalling Rails. Neither fixed the problem. Any ideas about what to try next?

Comment: your routes is not right. can you show routes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in config/routs.rb

```
  root '#index'
```

Generates an error, because it's missing a controller.

```
  root 'posts#index'
```

Includes a controller.